# Strapi/Nginx - Strapi routing does not work in production

Tags: nginx, routes, nginx-config, strapi

I created a website which uses a [nuxtjs](https://nuxtjs.org/) frontend and a [strapi](https://strapi.io/) backend. After deployment to a VPS, I cannot get the strapi routing to work. I read multiple posts about this on the internet and followed [the official documentation about nginx proxying](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/deployment/nginx-proxy.html#nginx-proxying) but to no evail.
**Path: /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    # Strapi API and Admin
    location /strapi/ {
        rewrite ^/strapi/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1337;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    }
}
```

**Path: backend/config/server.js**

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
  port: env.int('PORT', 1337),
  url: 'http://example.com/strapi',
});
```

Visiting example.com reveals the frontend, as intended. Visiting example.com/strapi reveals the following site:
[image]

Clicking on the 'Open admnistration' button leads me to example.com/admin, which returns my 404 frontend error page.

I would be very thankful for any kind of help.

Comment: Hello, what does http://example.com/strapi/admin ?

You configuration look good ([the new documentation is online](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/configurations.html#available-options))

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The way strapi is configured was meant to be used with the default root route, so use subdomains in this case.

Example `api.example.com` when you login to strapi it will hit `api.example.com/admin` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to use subdomains. But in your case the following urls to access strapi and the admin are :

- example.com/strapi
- example.com/strapi/admin

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with `npm run build` on strapi and then `npm run develop`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

the first location statement is matching with all your http calls
so even calls with /strapi path will be redirected to your front end app
i think you have to change the order
try to move

```
location /strapi/
```

before

```
location /
```

Comment: That is not correct. Please have a look at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

The example there clearly shows that locations with higher specificity are preferred.